# Force all user settings to save

Tags: c#, settings

I have a C# program with various setting stored in the program project settings. As it is a command line program, these settings will be changed by the user in the user.config file. I can't work out how to force it to save all the default values.

Calling `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` only seems to work when I update a property in the program, which defeats the point of a persistent settings file.

If I run

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SomeSetting = "Help";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

In the config file I will see something like

```
< setting name="SomeSetting" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Help</value>
< /setting>
```

What I want to happens is if the config file doesn't exist, create it and store all the settings. Then the user can change them if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I managed to solve it was by modifying some existing code I had in a different project to handle version upgrades.

When the program runs:

```
if (PropertiesSettings.Default.UpgradeRequired)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired = false;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    reloadSettings();
}

// Assign settings to themselves and save
// This keeps settings the same as the defaults even when upgrading but ensures all settings appear in the config file
private void reloadSettings()
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1 = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Setting2 = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting2;
    //etc
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

The `UpgradeRequired` setting should be set to True by default, so a new version with no config will be forced to run the first if statement. The .NET `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();` should then take care of finding old config files and loading the old settings.

Answer (score 0):

Settings are saved somewhere in user `AppData` folder specifically for a given process. For example, when the application is run under the debugger, you get different settings than when running stand-alone.

I would guess that there is no easy way to share settings across application using those properties settings. That code is quite old (.NET 2.0 or even before) so I think it is not designed to be easily customizable as it is often the case with more recent code.

I think that settings are good for things that are specific to a given application and if data need to be shared across application, then you should manage your own files.

Usually, one would use either XML or JSON based file and the data would be stored (by default) either under a subdirectory of `My Documents` if the data is intended to be visible to users or under a subdirectory of user application data directory if a regular user should not see those files.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. I'll add a bit more detail to the question.

Comment: Well, I think the real answer would be almost the same... I guess it would not be possible because that code was not designed in a way that would allows much customization. Thus, if the settings do not fit your need, you have write your own system.

Comment: An alternative might be to use a `PropertyGrid` to allow the user to edit settings from inside the application. That way, you would see all properties and if would even be somewhat more user friendly than editing the file directly.